# Security/Validation on c# property change N-Tier

Tags: c#, security, tampering

I have a class that keeps track of Property Changes

```
public class Property
        {
            object _OriginalValue;
            object _ProposedValue;
            DateTime _ProposedDateTime;
            List<Property> _History = new List<Property>();
            public object OriginalValue
            {
                get
                {
                    return _OriginalValue;
                }

                set
                {
                    _OriginalValue = value;
                }
            }
            public object ProposedValue
            {
                get
                {
                    return _ProposedValue;
                }

                set
                {
                    _ProposedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                    _ProposedValue = value;
                }
            }
            public bool IsDirty
            {
                get
                {

                    if (OriginalValue != ProposedValue)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This property can be used by classes like

```
 public class Customer
        {
            protected Property _FirstName = new Property();
            public string FirstName
            {
                get
                {
                    return (string)_FirstName.ProposedValue;
                }

                set
                {
                    _FirstName.ProposedValue = value;
                }
            }

            public object GetOriginalValue(Property Property)
            {
                return Property.OriginalValue;
            }

        }
```

The question is, is there a way to secure the original value when passing this to a client in an N-Tier architecture?

When a client passes a Customer back into the Service Boundary - by default you can't trust the client. You need to either reload the original values from the database or validate that the original values are untampered. Of course I'm assuming we're going to use business logic based on the current values in the customer to reject or allow an update operation.

Example:

User inserts record with Name Bob.

User fetches record with Name Bob and changes name to Ted. Original Value is Bob, proposed Value is Ted.

User sends Customer to Service to Update Customer.

Everything is good.

*A business rule is now coded into the service that says if the customer's name is Ted - allow the update else throw "unable to update" exception. *

User fetches record with name Ted. 
User changes name to Darren. 
User changes name back to Ted - system throws exception.
User fetches Ted. User cheats and uses a tool to change the OriginalPropertyValue on the client.
The server doesn't refetch the OriginalValue from the database and simply reads the OriginalValue coming from the client.

User bypasses business rule.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [TrackerDog](http://matiasfidemraizer.com/trackerdog) ([GitHub repository](https://github.com/mfidemraizer/trackerdog)). I feel that this will clean up your code a lot :)

Comment: Completely off topic. Code provided is simply to demonstrate the idea and is not actual production code. Thanks.

Comment: Feel free to post a solution using TrackerDog as an example. Make changes on the client, pass the changes to a server and validate that the client didn't change any original values set by a database or have a way to inject the current values from the db into the original values.

Comment: I was suggesting you TrackerDog just for the part of performing object change tracking, not as a direct answer to your issue.

Comment: TrackerDog works for xamarin (ios and android) - targetable by .netstandard 1.6?

Comment: I would love to port it to work on this scenarios as soon as possible. AFAIK, I can port it to work on .NET Core, since the guys from Castle Project have already released Castle.Core 4.0.0 which is compatible with .NET Core. So first step is .NET Core. If Castle.Core works on .NET Standard 1.6 (or any version), then TrackerDog will do too

Comment: Why don't you create an issue about .NET Standard compatibility so I can remember that I need to investigate it? https://github.com/mfidemraizer/trackerdog/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there're more issues with your approach than just checking if *original value* hasn't been tampered. For example, I suspect that's a multi-user environment where more than an user would be able to edit the same object. That is, the *original value* mightn't be tampered, but **changed before other has already saved a new *original value* in the database**.

I guess you're already applying some kind of optimistic or pessimistic locking on your data...

About your actual concern, probably you need to [*sign*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) your *original value*, and whenever you're going to store those objects back in the database, your application layer should check that *original value* hasn't been tampered (from Wikipedia):

> Digital signatures are a standard element of most cryptographic
>   protocol suites, and are commonly used for software distribution,
>   financial transactions, contract management software, and in other
>   cases where it is important to detect forgery or tampering.

Comment: Matias, before writing this post I've read of two ways to handle this: Repopulate the values on the server or of course apply some technique to make it tamper proof. What I'm really getting after is performance - does it cost more to hit a database or does it cost more to sign the original values. Certain Concurrency checks would block this type of attack (adding where clause to original values{where name=@Name}) as this would ignore the update if you didn't have the original values.

Comment: @Watson I would go for the signing approach. It's not a complicated process and today's CPU are ultra-powerful :) I'm pretty sure that querying the database has delays, about the total cost, we should make a performance test... It's not the same hitting SQL Server than Redis!